# Why does sed output -e expression #1, char 55: Invalid preceding regular expression

Tags: sed, rhel, regular-expression

I am tring to write sed command to find and replace a key=value in a comma delimited string.

**Example string in file:** `KEY_1=value_1,KEY_2=value_2,SOMEKEY=lastValue`

The sed command used:

```
sed -r 's/KEY_2=.*?((?=,)|$)/KEY_2=new_value/' myFile.txt
```

If the Key exists replace it and its value with a new key=value. Most of the values will end with a comma ',' however the outlying case is the last key=value in the string will not have a ,.

Its giving me the following error message on RedHat Linux VM

> sed: -e expression #1, char 55: Invalid preceding regular expression

which I believe is the last '/' I tried /g which would also be excptable as no key should be duplicated in the original string.

Comment: That looks like a Perl regex to me (lazy modifiers? zero-width lookarounds?).

Comment: `sed` does not support PCRE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `sed` utility does not support Perl-like regular expressions.

Instead you may use

```
$ sed 's/KEY_2=[^,]*/KEY_2=new value/' file
KEY_1=value_1,KEY_2=new value,SOMEKEY=lastValue
```

or

```
$ sed 's/\(KEY_2\)=[^,]*/\1=new value/' file
KEY_1=value_1,KEY_2=new value,SOMEKEY=lastValue
```

---

Or, with `awk`  (without using regular expressions and instead using exact string matches against the keys which prevents confusion when you have both `KEY_2` and `SOME_OTHER_KEY_2`):

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
                          if (split($i, a, "=") == 2 && a[1] == "KEY_2") {
                              $i = "KEY_2=new value"
                              break
                          } } 1' file
KEY_1=value_1,KEY_2=new value,SOMEKEY=lastValue
```

Comment: good one, especially the point about partial match

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, `sed` doesn't support PCRE style regular expressions (See also: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)). You can use `perl` instead

```
$ s='KEY_1=value_1,KEY_2=value_2,SOMEKEY=lastValue'

$ echo "$s" | perl -pe 's/KEY_2=.*?((?=,)|$)/KEY_2=new_value/'
KEY_1=value_1,KEY_2=new_value,SOMEKEY=lastValue

$ echo "$s" | perl -pe 's/SOMEKEY=.*?((?=,)|$)/SOMEKEY=new_value/'
KEY_1=value_1,KEY_2=value_2,SOMEKEY=new_value
```

You could simplify the regex:

```
$ # -l needed to prevent deleting the newline character for last field
$ echo "$s" | perl -lpe 's/KEY_2=\K[^,]+/new_value/'
KEY_1=value_1,KEY_2=new_value,SOMEKEY=lastValue

$ # to prevent partial match
$ echo "$s" | perl -lpe 's/(?<![^,])KEY_2=\K[^,]+/new_value/'
KEY_1=value_1,KEY_2=new_value,SOMEKEY=lastValue
```

See [perldoc Command Switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) for explanations on command line options used here